# Does google maps need api key for IOS application (and why)

Tags: ios, google-maps

I saw in this link 
http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#connectiphonetomysql 
Mr. Chris uses a google map without a key.[I've tried it and it's working]
but, when i enter google developer 
Here: https://developers.google.com/maps/ios/

 they say [get a key].

(why should i do it? i got confused)

if it's required to run it in my app, how can Chris did it?

pre-Thanks ^^.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Google map needs API key, without API key your request will be failed.

WHY: Every app is unique with its bundle ID, API key provided by google is used to identify the app uniquely.

There are so many paid services are offered by google to used in our app, App id used to manage your account based on request to API made/ package selected by you.

It also helps you to analyse use of google API through your app, which may may help you plan out your furthuer updates/usage to your App.

Comment: thank you for your explanation, I think it was a misunderstanding the example in the first link didn't use google map only a regular map, right?!.(sorry, I'm new with swift  ^^")

Comment: yes example in first link uses the Mapkit provided by Apple itself.